# How can I watch a folder on an sftp server for new files?

Tags: ftp, sftp, ls, watch

I log in to a sftp server, and to see the files I type `ls`. Is there any way to recursively watch a folder? For now I just keep typing `ls -tlh`. Is there a way for that to happen without me typing it? Like a `-watch` flag or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Despite the name, unix.stackexchange.com is the best place for *nix questions

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what you mean by "recursively watch" - your command does not appear to be doing any recursion or looking in any subdirectories.

Under linux the "watch" command can be used to repeatedly issue a command periodically - so I suspect you want

```
  watch -n1 'ls -tlh'
```

Which is equivalent to typing ls -tlh every second.   The default frequency is every 2 seconds (ie watch 'ls -tlh')

I don't think its what you want, but to answer the question as you asked it - if you want to see a tree of all the files and subdirectories in a subdirectory repeatedly, there is a utility "tree" (apt install tree under Ubuntu). You could then use

```
 watch 'tree /path/to/monitor'
```